# How to pass a value from a fluid page template into a ext:mask content element template?

Tags: typo3, typoscript, fluid, typo3-7.6.x, tx-mask

In TYPO3 7 LTS with ext:mask, I would like to pass a value from my page template into the FLUIDTEMPLATE that is rendered via the mask extension.

An example for what I'm trying to achieve:

> The content element has content that describes a car: A Volvo, 4WD...
>
> In the page template, I want to display that "car" in different
>   colors.  So the page template would be able to command: "get the first
>   car, and show it in green. Then the second car and show it in yellow".
>   (and no, it's got nothing to do with css..)

If this has to be done once onan entire page, I can use

```
`tt_content.default.mask_car.settings.color = green`
```

Or (for the record) if the purpose of that variable would be to modify the presentation, I could use:

```
`tt_content.default.mask_car.settings.file = path/to/Mask/Content/Templates/car_green.html`
```

**But** if there are several instances of the same content element on the page, that approach is no good.

How to pass different values into different instances of the same CE on a page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could add following TypoScript:

```
lib.set_register = LOAD_REGISTER
lib.set_register.color = TEXT
lib.set_register.color.current = 1

lib.get_register.color = TEXT
lib.get_register.color.data = register:color

lib.mask_car < styles.content.get
lib.mask_car.select.where = colPos=123
```

And within your page template you set the color with Fluid

```
<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.set_register.color" data="green"/>
```

Get your content elements with Fluid

```
<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.mask_car"/>
```

And switch the content element's out put within your mask template with Fluid

```
<f:if condition="{f:cObject(typoscriptObjectPath: 'lib.get_register.color')} == 'green'">
    <f:then>
        green
    </f:then>
    <f:else>
        not green
    </f:else>
</f:if>
```

I hope this helps you to solve your problem.

Comment: Wooohoo! I've tested it and it works perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem:
A collection of mask content elements; two different renderings of the same element on the same page:

- One random mask-ce rendered as teaser, linking to the detail on the bottom of the page
- A list of all mask ce's rendered as list-items (detail)

  My solution:

Rendering of the random teaser:

```
lib.qa_random_teaser_community < styles.content.get
lib.qa_random_teaser_community.select{
  where = colPos=12
  pidInList = {$pidCommunityQAStorage}
  max = 1
  orderBy = rand()
}
```

Rendering of the detail list:

```
lib.qa_list_community < styles.content.get
lib.qa_list_community{
  renderObj < tt_content
  renderObj.default.mask_qa_community.settings.renderListItems = 1
  select {
    where = colPos=12
    pidInList = {$pidCommunityQAStorage}
  }
}
```

I copy the tt_content to renderObj, then I can modify it, adding a dedicated setting for the mask element just for this content rendering:

```
renderObj.default.mask_qa_community.settings.renderListItems = 1
```

In the mask template, I just have to check for the setting and trigger the appropriate rendering:

```
<f:if condition="{settings.renderListItems}">
  <f:then>
    <f:render section="qa-detail" arguments="{data:data}"/>
  </f:then>
  <f:else>
    <f:render section="qa-teaser" arguments="{data:data}"/>
  </f:else>
</f:if>
```

Another approach would be to select a dedicated fluid-template instead of just feeding a setting:

```
renderObj.default.mask_qa_community.settings.file = .......
```

In Mask 3.0.1 with TYPO3 8...

```
renderObj.mask_qa_community.settings.file = .......
```

Hope it's useful for someone else.

Answer (score 0):

I'm revisiting this question, in TYPO3 9 with mask 4.x, this works:

```
lib.my_content_element {
  renderObj.mask_content_text.settings.test = 123
}
```

Comment: I don't know how to switch the template file completely. Not sure if it still works.